# Logtool for desktopapplication

Tags: c#

I've created this small tool in C# that deletes a record in a database. So instead of opening and writing SQL I now just enter the specifics and the small application deletes it for me.

But now I need to allowe everyone access to this small application. So I need a way to log what they user deleted (recordid and stuff). Could I just plainly do a write to file? What happens if two or more users are using the application at the same time?

Comment: Add an audit table and a trigger to log the action of who did what. That is assuming that your connections are based on user logins and not a database user.

Answer (score 0):

The question might be what exectaly you want to achive. where you want to write log into sql database or into files. or you want to send an email to your self or somebody else. if you have one of these question in your mind. just use [LOG4NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14819/How-to-use-log4net)

What you have to do is use this utility into your application and add its logging into desire location.

if you want to log into sql server what you can do is use Delete trigger in your tables and log what users have deleted.